# Java script pausing the script before the browser closes

Tags: javascript

Sorry im very new to coding so speak to me like a 5 year old lol but i wanted the script to pause before the browser closes for like 20 seconds, java script

```
      await page.goto('http://httpbin.org/ip');
      const infos = await create_accinfos(browser, page);
      write_log(true, "Complete infos");
      accounts.write(infos + "\n");
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      write_log(true, "Done");
      try{
        browser.close();
      } catch(e){};
    }
  })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_win_settimeout.asp) method.

```
setTimeout(() => { browser.close(); }, 20000)
```

After 20 seconds (20 000 milliseconds) the browser will be closed.

Comment: What about trying to understand the code first? It is really important to know how it works than implement random code from somewhere (so you don't know what to modify).